# iphone: Sending multitouch from the device to the simulator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to record a video of a multitouch game I'm working on, and I'd like to record it from the simulator. My idea was to send touches from the device to the simulator (like [this project](http://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/wiki/Home) does with the accelerometer). Just by googling I haven't found anything like that, but before I start implementing it I thought I'd ask here if anyone knows about an already existing solution.

Just to be clear, I do need full multitouch (up to 5 fingers). The pinch and drag that are available on the simulator are not enough.

Comment: I spent some time and managed to modify the accelerometer-simulator project to intercept the touches and broadcast them, but I'm stuck on the receiving end.  I can receive them just fine, but I have no idea how to generate a UIEvent to send to UIApplication's sendEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Gallagher has a writeup on [synthesizing touch events](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html), which might provide what you're looking for, although I've not tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/), it is an application/library pair that allows you to use to multi-touch (up to 5 fingers), the accelerometer, and the GPS in the iPhone Simulator. It takes only few minutes to integrate into your iPhone project.